# Using different resource files depending of the SDK API level (using Eclipse)?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am writing an Android app, targeting API levels 8 to 14. I want to use the Theme.Holo.Light theme for API level 11 and higher, and a Theme.Light theme for lower API levels.

The content of res/values/style.xml is:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" />
</resources>
```

and the content of res/values-v11/style.xml is:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light" />
</resources>
```

This compiles well for API level 14, but when setting my target API level to 8, it gives the following error: "**Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'**" in **res/values-v11/style.xml**, and "**Android AAPT Problem**".

If I remove the file **res/values-v11/style.xml**, the app compiles correctly for API level 8 target.

Now, my understanding is that when compiling for API level 8 the build system should ignore anything inside a resource folder whose name ends with "-v11".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because API 8 got no clue what Theme.Holo.Light is as it was introduced in API11. You have to  compile against **highest** API version you use elements of.

And you understand resource selectors wrong. It's is not used for build the app conditionally. It's used to pick up right resource **at runtime**.

See [this article](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html).

Comment: Let me see if I understand you correctly: I should compile for API 14, and the same compiled code (providing I only use API calls that are supported by API 8) will run on anything from API 8 to API 14?

Comment: Yes. And assuming your code is not using API14 methods without prior checking what API device runs on, it will run just fine on any API from `minSdkVersion` onwards. This lets you have one binary for many APIs and resource selectors lets you separate i.e. assets or differentiate some elements like you did w/o need to build separate binaries for each API version